# Dynamically defining columns name for unknown column names in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to extract hog features of an images. after extracting hog features of one image I want to put into a dataframe as one row. and so on... for next image.
Here is the code I am using.

Problem: The problem I am facing is unknown column count.. this code work only if I have column names given as shown in line ---(1). but in hog features I can't give column name as these are in thousands.

Kindly help me solve this issue.

All I want any number of element in the list should go into dataframe as a row. and next image as next row and so on....

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.transform import resize
from skimage.feature import hog
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from numpy import *

data_path = "/content/drive/My Drive/ADIP/seperate_ricepests8/seperate_ricepests8/"

image_hog = pd.DataFrame()
image_hog2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7","a8"]) #--------(1)   

labels = os.listdir(data_path)
for dirname in labels:
    filepath = os.path.join(data_path, dirname)
    print("Extracting ",dirname," ... ")
    for file in os.listdir(filepath):
        filename = os.path.join(filepath, file)       
        image = cv2.imread(filename)
        image_resized = cv2.resize(image, (300,300))
        image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        df = pd.DataFrame()

        image_gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        resized_img = resize(image_gray2, (128, 64))
        fd, hog_image = hog(resized_img, orientations=9, pixels_per_cell=(8, 8), cells_per_block=(2, 2), visualize=True, multichannel=False)
        hog_flat = hog_image.flatten()   
        df = hog_flat.tolist()
        print(fd)
        image_hog2.loc[len(df)+1] = df
        image_hog = image_hog.append(image_hog2)
    print(dirname,"ok!")

hog_f = image_hog.to_numpy()  # this line
ho=hog_f.flatten()   # this line
print(ho)
```

Getting error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way of creating Dataframe. Where data can have lists with diff no of elements. And at the end you can just name the columns as you wish.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2], [4,3,2]])
```

Comment: No that is not correct.... please see above code question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps but maybe construct your frame after the looping?

The code below creates random lists of different lengths and then concats them into one final dataframe.

**Example:**

```
import random
import pandas as pd


# create some frames and store in a list
randomlist = []
for i in range(0,10):
    randomlist.append(random.sample(range(10, 30), random.randint(1,10)))

# build frame from a list of different length lists
df = pd.DataFrame(randomlist)

# rename columns 0,1,2,3 etc. to a1, a2, a3 etc.
df.columns = ['a' + str(col+1) for col in df.columns]

print(df, '\n\n')


####################
######## or ########
####################


# dictionary to store all the frames that we'll generate below
dfs = {}

# create some frames
for i in range(0,10):
    df = pd.DataFrame((random.sample(range(10, 30), random.randint(1,10))))
    dfs[i] = df

# concat the frames in the dict together
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).T.reset_index(drop=True).T

# rename columns 0,1,2,3 etc. to a1, a2, a3 etc.
df.columns = ['a' + str(col+1) for col in df.columns]

print(df, '\n\n')
```

**Output:**

```
   a1  a2    a3    a4    a5    a6    a7    a8    a9   a10
0  15  17   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1  11  12  10.0  24.0  19.0  13.0  16.0  18.0  22.0   NaN
2  18  11  26.0  16.0  14.0  27.0  23.0  24.0  13.0   NaN
3  22  27  11.0  19.0  24.0  20.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
4  21  24  16.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
5  27  28  23.0  10.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
6  22  21  18.0  15.0  28.0  13.0  19.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
7  26  23  16.0  21.0  11.0  17.0  20.0  22.0   NaN   NaN
8  13  19  28.0  12.0  26.0  10.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
9  20  19  22.0  29.0  17.0  28.0  27.0  16.0  23.0  13.0 


     a1    a2    a3    a4    a5    a6    a7    a8    a9   a10
0  20.0  10.0  17.0  26.0  10.0  18.0  25.0  11.0  13.0  25.0
1  21.0  19.0  12.0  24.0  20.0   NaN  28.0  24.0  14.0  11.0
2  10.0  14.0  21.0  21.0  25.0   NaN  29.0  15.0  27.0  22.0
3  29.0  27.0  24.0  27.0  14.0   NaN  22.0   NaN  28.0  26.0
4  13.0  20.0  27.0   NaN  17.0   NaN  26.0   NaN  21.0   NaN
5  23.0   NaN  18.0   NaN  19.0   NaN  10.0   NaN  10.0   NaN
6  26.0   NaN  23.0   NaN  23.0   NaN  23.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
7  12.0   NaN  13.0   NaN  18.0   NaN  12.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
8   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  24.0   NaN  15.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
9   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  21.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
```